# Add object array to listview in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Would you please let me know how can I fill listview with this object array in Xamarin form.

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "CODE": "B25-4126"
        },
        {
            "CODE": "F1-2228"
        }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create Model for JSON result as follows:

```
public class Product
{
public string CODE { get; set; }
}

public class ProductList
{
public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```

Now deserialize json to model ProductList and assign it ItemSource property of listview

Comment: Welcome fattaneh :)